# Creating a websocket ping in vanilla browser JS

Tags: javascript, websocket

I've searched a lot but cannot find a specific example of how to send - using javascript - a ping over a websocket (https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455#section-5.5.2) from the browser. I'm told that the server I'm using will reply to a ping, but I've been trying variations on the following theme without success.

```
var sockets= {};
// ... code that attaches sockets to this object

for (let key in sockets) {
    console.log("about to send pings to", key)
    sockets[key].send(0x9)
}
```

Comment: are you using any library ?

Comment: vanilla javascript

Answer (score 0):

```
const ws = new WebSocket('URL goes here');
ws.onopen = () => { ws.send('ping') };
ws.onmessage = (data) => { console.log(data); } // this should be pong
```

EDIT the script that you'll need,

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/web-socket-js/1.0.0/web_socket.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I should be sending something called `0x9` but don't know how to express that

Comment: if you are using websockets then you can directly send `ping` as a string,